# Is this an empty product?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, products

Assume that we have:
$$\Psi_{j,k}=(t_{j+1}-\tau)\times...\times(t_{j+k-1}-\tau)$$
that  can be written as:

$$\Pi_{i=j+1}^{j+k-1} (t_i-\tau)$$

If we have $k=1$ , my text-book says that  this is an empty product and equals $1$ by definition.

It seems to make sense because in this case the "upper limit" of the product is lower than the lower one, but following the first expression, couldn't we write

$$\Psi_{j,1}=(t_{j+1}-\tau)\times(t_{j}-\tau)$$

Is this wrong? I am not familiar with this notation and it may be very trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read : $\Pi_{i=j+1}^{j+k-1} (t_i-\tau)$ as

"*The product of $t_i - \tau$ **FROM** $j+1$ **TO** $j+k-1$*"

Now if $j+1$ is less than $j+k-1$, than the previous assertion makes no sense and by convention we replace the product by $1$.

Comment: Using the same logic if $k=2$ we also have an empty product?

Comment: as I explained, no, you would there have then a single factor (by popping in the definition via the product), which is $\psi_{j+1}-\tau$

Answer (score 1):

no, you can't, since the above definition is suggestive to make clear that youmultiply all between $j+1$ and $j+k-1$. I understand that the first definition would look like  $\psi_{j,1}=(t_{j+1}-\tau)\times (t_j - \tau)$. I myself prefer to exclude those boundary cases in my definitions and define them seperately, but sometimes you just do not have the time, space or simply forgot.
in my opinion your second equation would be the better definition, and your top line a remark about what that means for $k> 2$

Comment: makes completely sense, but I am not sure where $k>j+2$ comes from, if we set $k=3$ for instance the line above works perfectly: $(t_{j+1}-\tau)\times( t_{j+3-1}-\tau)$ irrespective of the value of $j$

Comment: you are right, I am sorry, I messed it up with notations I usually use (if I got sums like that I usually either index from 0 by force or run between two one variable ends).
also, thanks a lot, I edited my answer now!